# Importing XML from WS and parsing in access table in VBA

Tags: xml, ms-access, xml-parsing, vba

I am working to import data from a web service. I am successful with that but the data imports in 3 tables. I have found various options that i think will work but confused as to which option would be best and make most sense.

Options i've found are

Transforming XML using XSLT
Multiple ways of parsing including XPATH

Really i've read so much im getting to the point of confusion of what i should be doing.

Here is the XML

```
<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Xata.Ignition.WebServiceAPI.Contracts.DataContract.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vehicle>
        <AllowTrailerInspection>true</AllowTrailerInspection>
        <Auxiliary>None</Auxiliary>
        <CompanyName>Company</CompanyName>
        <CompanySID>1234</CompanySID>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <EldVehicle>true</EldVehicle>
        <FuelDrawCapacity>0</FuelDrawCapacity>
        <GrossVehicleWeight>0</GrossVehicleWeight>
        <HP>0</HP>
        <HUT>false</HUT>
        <HasBerth>false</HasBerth>
        <HasElectronicEngine>true</HasElectronicEngine>
        <HosExempt>false</HosExempt>
        <IFTA>true</IFTA>
        <InstallDate>2018-10-01T13:01:00</InstallDate>
        <LicensePlate></LicensePlate>
        <ManualVIN>false</ManualVIN>
        <Manufacture></Manufacture>
        <ManufactureDate>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ManufactureDate>
        <Model></Model>
        <ModifiedBy>331</ModifiedBy>
        <ModifiedDate>2018-10-19T20:26:03.648543</ModifiedDate>
        <OBCType>ABCRelay</OBCType>
        <Odometer>0</Odometer>
        <OdometerDate>2018-10-01T04:00:00</OdometerDate>
        <OrganizationID>ABCLTL</OrganizationID>
        <OrganizationName>ABCLTL</OrganizationName>
        <OrganizationSID>32</OrganizationSID>
        <OwnerOperator>false</OwnerOperator>
        <PowerAxles>1</PowerAxles>
        <ResourceGroupIdList xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:string>NOR DISPATCH</a:string>
        </ResourceGroupIdList>
        <SID>34163</SID>
        <StateProvince>Texas</StateProvince>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <StraightTruck>false</StraightTruck>
        <TGTNumber>123456</TGTNumber>
        <TransmissionMfg></TransmissionMfg>
        <TransmissionType></TransmissionType>
        <Type>Tractor</Type>
        <UserDefinedField1></UserDefinedField1>
        <UserDefinedField2></UserDefinedField2>
        <UserDefinedField3></UserDefinedField3>
        <UserDefinedField4></UserDefinedField4>
        <UserDefinedField5></UserDefinedField5>
        <VIN>1FVAHGFCXAJJR8537</VIN>
        <VehicleName>001234SCAC</VehicleName>
        <Year></Year>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
```

I am only wanting to import

```
<VehicleName>
<TGTNumber> and
<a:string> inside of <ResourceGroupIDList....
```

This is what I have thus far in VBA

```vb
Public Sub UpdateTrucks(strUID As String, strPassword As String)
    'Debug.Print strDate
    Dim reader As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim strUserID As String
    Dim strRequest As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset



    strSQL = "tblResourceGroups1"   'defines the Table result that you want to loop
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    strUserID = "1234567|" & strUID
    strPassword = strPassword

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    While (Not rs.EOF)

            strRequest = "http://ws.Website.com/VehicleWebService.svc/vehicles/?ResourceGroupID=" & rs.Fields("ResourceGroupName")
            'Debug.Print strRequest
            reader.Open "GET", strRequest, rs.Fields("ResourceGroupName"), strUserID, strPassword
            reader.send

                Do Until reader.ReadyState = 4
                    DoEvents
            Loop

            If reader.status = 200 Then
            'importXML

            'current
            Set doc = reader.responseXML
            doc.Save "C:\Data\Table.xml"
            Application.ImportXML "C:\Data\Table.xml", acStructureAndData

                ElseIf reader.status = 401 Then
                   MsgBox "Unable to authenticate. The username and password do not match with the system."
                ElseIf reader.status = 500 Then
                   MsgBox "Due to an internal issue the system is unable to take the desired request. Please try again later."
            End If

        rs.MoveNext
      Wend
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to import data."

    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing


End Sub
```

Any help on the direction i should go would be much appreciated.

Comment: If every XML file is just a single row in a table, and you just want to import 3 fields, I recommend doing it manually: write  up XPATH queries to select the relevant nodes, store their data in a variable, and either open up a recordset and insert the data or use an insert query. That also avoids writing it to disk, reading it back from disk, then cleaning up after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files such as your extraction needs. Run the XSLT script just after you retrieve the web XML object and before calling `ImportXML`.

Specifically the XSLT below runs the Identity Transform (to copy document as is) and then extracts from all *Vehicle* nodes, the three needed child elements. Here, XSLT maps default namespace to *doc* prefix.

**XSLT** *(save as an .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Xata.Ignition.WebServiceAPI.Contracts.DataContract.Entities"
                              xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">                            
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:Vehicle">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="doc:VehicleName|doc:TGTNumber|doc:ResourceGroupIdList/a:string"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
' ADD MSXML, v6.0 REFERENCE UNDER TOOLS
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

... same code ...

' WEB XML DOC
Set doc = reader.responseXML

' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.LoadXML doc.XML

xslDoc.async = False
xslDoc.Load "C:\Data\XSLT_Script.xsl"

' TRANSFORM XML
xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

' OUTPUT TRANSFORMED XML
newDoc.Save "C:\Data\Table.xml"

' IMPORT TRNASFORMED XML
Application.ImportXML "C:\Data\Table.xml", acStructureAndData

... same code ...
```

**XML** *(transformed)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Xata.Ignition.WebServiceAPI.Contracts.DataContract.Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vehicle>
        <a:string xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">NOR DISPATCH</a:string>
        <TGTNumber>123456</TGTNumber>
        <VehicleName>001234SCAC</VehicleName>
    </Vehicle>
</ArrayOfVehicle>
```

**MS Access Table**

```
string       TGTNumber  VehicleName
NOR DISPATCH    123456   001234SCAC
```

Comment: You my friend out this is a way where it all made sense. this is working perfect. Thank you so much.